# Second Order Relationship in Graph Database

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, relationships

I'm creating an app which is quite relationship heavy.  One of the features of the site is a recommendation feature, where users can rate things for others.  For this, it seems like a Graph DB would be ideal so I am planning on using Neo4j, alongside Ruby.

This all seems fairly straight forward, however I would like to include a feature where users can rate a specific relationship.  For example, a user could recommend a hotdog in a specific restaurant, etc.  The only way I can really think about doing this with a Graph DB is to either add a 'joining node' between the two nodes, connecting all three, or by adding lists of properties to the relationship (ie adding hotdog_5 to the user-restaurant relationship).  Obviously the rating could just be added to the hotdog-restaurant relationship, but you wouldn't be able to trace the users that rated it, to prevent them rating more than once.

Any thoughts on the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to retrieve all the comments from a user, or the comments about hotdogs in all restaurant, or all the comments about all type of food in a restaurant so I would recommend to do it like :

```
1. user-[:write]->comment
2. comment-[:about]->hotdog
3. comment-[:concern]->restaurant
4.restaurant-[serve]->hotdog
```

Not sure about the last one it may be useless due to 2 and 3, it depend a lot on the queries you'll run

Comment: So you suggest that I create an additional node between all three items, and attach a rating and comment property to that? That makes sense, and I considered this in my question, but wasn't sure if there were a more efficient way of doing this with relationship properties?

Comment: You can even boost results based on attributes on the relationships, see for instance http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-boostingrecommendations.html